# How to say "In the morning/afternoon/evening"?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering what the various ways of saying in the morning/afternoon/evening are... I would expect to be able to say あさ/ひる/よる に... but in the course I'm doing I never see this, they "ni" is usually omitted, or change for a "ha".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, に is attached to temporal markers that do have a numeric value, whereas it is not attached to those temporal markers that do not have a number. The exception are the weekdays, for which both options are acceptable.

**With に**

> 10時【じ】に、3月【がつ】に、2005年【ねん】に…

**Without に**

> 朝【あさ】、昼【ひる】、夜【よる】、毎月【まいつき】、先週【せんしゅう】、この間【あいだ】、and many, many more…

**Either with or without に**

> 日曜日【にちようび】、火曜日【かようび】、水曜日【すいようび】、…
>   日曜日に、火曜日に、水曜日に、…

---

Source: 「みんなの日本語 初級 Ⅰ」Lesson 4, Grammar Explanation

[image]

Comment: how does 午前中 fit in with your theory? I always see this used with に ...

Comment: I simply don't know. But so far I've been following this rule and it is consistent, wouldn't assure its like this 100% of the time though. I studied it this way, I included the source (my textbook) in the answer for clarification, please take a look to it. They do not say a thing regarding words such as 午前中 or in general "temporal noun + 中". Maybe this construction follows its own rules? In any case, I found some resources ([see point 3 here](http://maggiesensei.com/2015/01/06/how-to-use-中chuu/)) where they explain the use of "t-noun + 中" and they do not use に.